# How to get client's external IPv4 address in ASP.NET without using external services?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, ip

I'm currently using the following function to get external IPv4 address of my client:

```
public static string GetExternalIP()
        {
            try
            {
                string externalIP;
                externalIP = (new WebClient()).DownloadString("http://checkip.dyndns.org/");
                externalIP = (new Regex(@"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"))
                             .Matches(externalIP)[0].ToString();
                return externalIP;
            }
            catch { return null; }
        }
```

Is there any other way to get the same result without using any external website or services?

Comment: Are you sure that's the IP of your Client?

Comment: I have tested it with my own IP address and it was the same. But I'm also trying to get the internal IPv4 but I don't know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. because actually only when you're connecting to a server he can tell you where you come from... so There is not any other option except making a connection to another service. its pretty fast tho... (if this what bothered you..) Hope you understood.

Comment: Thank you, I thought so. It's exactly because of the connection, sometimes it takes about 10+ seconds to get the response.

Comment: @KevinMaxwell yeah.. you know what i think Open.Nat actually does somthing similar.. i'll look it up for you..

Comment: @KevinMaxwell no.. they also request it from a service.. i just tried  http://checkip.dyndns.org/ and it was really fast.. i think that's the most efficient and stable site for reteriving your ip.. by the way if you would like to not freeze the aplication while retreiving the Ip adress-just use it on a thread or use async method.. notify me if you need some help with that. Good luck

Comment: I think you are reading my mind. I actually want to put a "Loader" while it's fetching the IP address.

Comment: @KevinMaxwell haha allright...lets do it. i'll edit my post :)

Comment: @KevinMaxwell by the way- is it winform or wpf?

Comment: You are amazing, let's do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86885/discussion-between-slashy-and-kevin-maxwell).

Answer (score 2):

### GET INTERNAL IP ADDRESS

```
protected string GetInternalIP()
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
            string ipAddress = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
            {
                string[] addresses = ipAddress.Split(',');
                if (addresses.Length != 0)
                {
                    return addresses[0];
                }
            }

            return context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        }
```

### GET EXTERNAL IP ADDRESS

```
    public static string GetExternalIP()
    {
        try
        {
            string externalIP;
            externalIP = (new WebClient()).DownloadString("http://checkip.dyndns.org/");
            externalIP = (new Regex(@"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"))
                         .Matches(externalIP)[0].ToString();
            return externalIP;
        }
        catch { return null; }
    }
```